# Transmitting data via quantum fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

Actually I was thinking that currently we are able to transmit data via Photons which are excitation in the EM FIELD, but if there exist any other quantum fields, why couldn't we use the excitation in them to transmit data, so that can we transmit data faster than speed of light?

Thank you for your responses btw but I still need some clarity like
We all know that Photons are the force mediators for EM FIELD
SO like the same we have others like gluon etc. which meadiate strong force via it's quantum field, I wonder that can we use sucha particle to transmit data

I certainly agree that Photons will always travel at their own speed,which we perceive as the speed limit of the universe, but what if the other force mediating particles (or excitation) can have speed great that *c* ?

1. List item

Comment: There *are* other quantum fields, but they don’t go faster than light. It’s the speed limit for everything.

Comment: Please see my question once more , I have included more infos

Comment: *what if the other force mediating particles (or excitation) can have speed great that $c$ ?* They can’t.

Comment: But I'm gonna assume it that they can indeed

Comment: On this site, only mainstream physics is on-topic. Non-mainstream “what if” assumptions make a question off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

All fields in our universe are limited to the speed of light for propagation.

If you want long-range communication, you need a massless excitation. For it to be practical, you need an easy & cheap way to both generate and then detect the excitations. Ordinary photons are therefore ideal for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  Please check my question once again, I have added more information recently